# Google chart bug? Axis not starting at 0

Tags: google-visualization

The following example is from Google to create a ColumnChart using Google Charts

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Czech Republic', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany'],
    ['2003', 1336060, 3817614, 974066, 1104797, 6651824, 15727003],
    ['2004', 1538156, 3968305, 928875, 1151983, 5940129, 17356071],
    ['2005', 1576579, 4063225, 1063414, 1156441, 5714009, 16716049],
    ['2006', 1600652, 4604684, 940478, 1167979, 6190532, 18542843],
    ['2007', 1968113, 4013653, 1037079, 1207029, 6420270, 19564053],
    ['2008', 1901067, 6792087, 1037327, 1284795, 6240921, 19830493]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
  draw(data, {
    title: "Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    hAxis: {
      title: "Year"
    }
  });
}
```

Which works perfectly, however, I only want one value per column so I change it to:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Month', 'How many'],
    ['07', 193],
    ['08', 114],
    ['09', 158]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
  draw(data, {
    title: "Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    hAxis: {
      title: "Year"
    }
  });
}
```

And now the vertical axis doesn't start at 0 but close to the lowest value, in this case 114 - is this a bug? I still want it to show from 0 as it's very confusing at a quick glance like this

Any ideas?

Comment: I have only noticed this behaviour on the combo column charts (Feb '16)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to pass another parameter as part of the options when drawing the chart.

```
vAxis: {minValue: 0}
```

That will force the vertical axis to start from 0, you can see other possible options here: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#Configuration_Options

Comment: Thank you for this, I've always added a row with 0 :)

Answer (score 32):

If you haven't data at the graph `vAxis: {minValue: 0}` will not help. So you can use configuration option `viewWindow`:

```
var options = { 
    vAxis: { 
        viewWindow: {
            min:0
        }
    }
};
var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who still searching the way to make the axes start 0, you can try this options.

```
vAxes: {
  0: {baseline: 0},
},
```

Note that I used vAxes instead of vAxis. I'm not sure why, but that did the trick.

I get the answer here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/vRNJUk9aZUI